# How Hibernate updates an entity with collection from detached state using update?

Tags: java, hibernate

When we use :

```
session.update(entity) //in hibernate, doc says an update sql is guaranteed.
```

It also says

> One way to avoid this UDPATE statement is to configure the class
>   mapping of Item with the select-before-update="true" attribute.

So if i have an entity `A` with `List<B>`, and remove an element from `List` in detached object of `A`. I believe hibernate has to make a select call before update sql even when i haven't used above class mapping.
To determine removed instance of `B`

And if in this case no change is detected, is update to `A` prevented?